# Get drone's position in indoor in Android

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, point-cloud-library

I have a static point cloud file, which I am able to render in Android. But I am unable to get the drone's location, which I have to show on that point cloud in real time.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Getting indoor position is hard - as far as I know GPS does not work. Maybe you need some ultrasound senders on your drone? You'll need to spend a good amount of time on a search engine for this.